# Lync Edge and Exchange Server: how to have access to my exchange mailbox from external network and also to the OWA

Tags: exchange-2010, lync, exchange

I've some problem in the configuration of Exchange 2010.

My topology is like that:

1. Server1 = Domain Controller
2. Server2 = Exchange Server
3. Server3 = Lync Server
4. Server4 = Lync Edge

Our public address (the one accessible by outside world) is directed to Server4.

I would like to have access to my exchange mailbox from external network and also to the OWA.

Could you help me in the configuration of thoses servers?

Thank in advance

Julien

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a Firewall / Reverse Proxy in front of all your servers e.g. Something link Microsoft Forefront TMG.

That is then set up with your external IP address and routes all inbound web requests to the various boxes (Lync, OWA etc.) based on a set of "Publishing Rules"

Note that the above is a very simplistic description of what is a potentially a more complicated project and doesn't reflect the amount of effort and knowledge you will need in order to set this up.

I suggest you read up on firewalls and reverse proxies in order to gain more insight into your options.

Comment: I see on some forum that's possible to install tmg on lync edge.
What do you think about that?